# Slow queries from commandline mysql and phpMyAdmin, but not from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm facing a strange issue. I have an API which calls tens of times per second some queries to a couple of really crowded tables (at least for our standards, **15M** and **42M**). These calls are `selects`, `updates` and `inserts`, and are really, really fast; even though we may be calling 30 updates in just one API call, the whole call is finished in **less than 0.05 seconds**.

*However*, when I want to check some of these rows through `phpMyAdmin`, using the same exact query the API is using, it turns out the **Apache server crashes**, due to timeout.

What's more of an X-file, is that if I issue the same query through the `mysql` cli, it doesn't crash the `Apache` anymore (obviously), **but the data server**. It's a fairly short blackout (less than a second), but it even pops me out of the commandline interface.

A similar query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM one_of_the_tables 
WHERE this_field != '' 
    AND CHAR_LENGTH(this_field) < 8 
LIMIT 50
```

After the first fails, I started adding a limit to this. I know `CHAR_LENGTH`'s not the fastest out there, but I mean, 50 rows is not that much.